# htaccess Rewrite rule not working as I expected

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ip=$1 [L]
```

But it's not working, instead it is loading:

```
https://example.com/?ip=index.php
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to load?

Comment: When i type `https://example.com/[ip address]` it should load `https://example.com/?ip=[ip address]`. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is looping because there is no condition to stop rewriting for existing files and directories.

After first rewrite it becomes:

```
index.php?id=1.2.3.4
```

and after second rewrite URI becomes:

```
index.php?id=index.php
```

You can use this rule to fix this behavior:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?ip=$1 [L,QSA]
```